# Is there a simple method for checking whether a Ruby IO instance will block on read()?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, io, nonblocking

I'm looking for a method in Ruby which is basically this:

```
io.ready_for_read?
```

I just want to check whether a given `IO` object (in my case, the result of a `popen` call) has output available, i.e. a follow up call `io.read(1)` will not block.

These are the two options I see, neither of which I like:

1. `io.read_nonblock` - too thin an abstraction of Unix `read()` -- I don't want to deal with `errno` error handling.
2. `io.select` with timeout 0 -- obfuscates the purpose of this simple operation.

Is there a better alternative that I have overlooked?

Comment: I don't /think/ so. This is really what select is for. Yes, select has horrible syntax, but I guess in theory you could monkeypatch a "ready_for_read?" type method into IO that uses select.

Comment: That `IO#ready_for_read?` implementation doesn't work for me - it always returns true. I think the problem is that `IO#select` blocks until the stream is opened for writing by another process (which in my case it always already is), not until there is actual data to be read. I'm trying to track down another way to achieve this but I'm not having much luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit late, but if you `require 'io/wait'`, you can use `ready?` to verify that the IO can be read without blocking.  Granted, depending upon how much you intend on reading (and how you plan to do it) your IO object may still block, but this should help.  I'm not sure if this library is supported on all platforms, and I also don't know why this functionality was separated from the rest of the IO library.  See more here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/io/wait/rdoc/

Answer (score 6):

I'm ready to conclude that no, there is no simple method to do this.  Per Peter Cooper's suggestion, here is `IO#ready_for_read?`:

```
class IO
  def ready_for_read?
    result = IO.select([self], nil, nil, 0)
    result && (result.first.first == self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I've seen some inconsistencies with **IO/wait**.  The ruby I have here right now is:

*ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32]*

On this one both **nread** and **ready?** are implemented, but they return erroneous results.  On a different version that I was using **ready?** was still broken and **nread** didn't even exist.

One possibility is to use **io.stat.size**, which tells you the number of bytes available to read in an IO stream.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File/Stat.html

The documentation suggests that it's for files, but I've used it on pipes connected to a separate process (via Ruby's Open3.popen3).  It's worked for me so far.

Comment: No-repro for STDIN. It reads zero even though there definitely is data to read.